# Re-source a file whenever I save a vim file

Tags: vimrc

I would like to set an autocommand that automatically resources the file whenever I save it, as now I am doing something like:

```
:w | so %
```

Whenever I save something.

What would be the correct 'event' to do this with? For example:

```
augroup uncompress
    au!
    au (BufWritePre? BufWritePost? BufWrite? BufWriteCmd? FileWritePre? etc.) *.vim  :so %<CR>
augroup END
```

What is the main difference between `BufWrite` and `FileWrite` ? From the docs it seems pretty similar:

> **BufferWritePre** starting to write the whole buffer to a file

> **FileWritePre** starting to write part of a buffer to a file

Answer (score 3):

While answering questions here , I often write little Vim script files to test something. To automatically source the file, I use the following command:

```
command! VimTest autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> redraw! | source % | echo 'Sourced ' . fnamemodify(expand('%'), ':t')
```

When I decide that the current script should be re-sourced on every save, I execute `:VimTest`.

This installs a buffer-local autocmd  that

1. forces a redraw (to remove Vim's write message `filename <lines>L, chars>C`)
2. sources the just saved file
3. Prints that the file was sourced.

In this special case I do it without a `augroup`, that I would normally *always* recommend.

See `:h autocmd-buflocal`.

Comment: I see. Why do you cuse the `BurWritePost` event here (as opposed to `FileWritePost` or some of the other events)? Could you please explain why that event is the best suited for this particular task?

Comment: @David542 This is a buffer-local autocmd (I've added the help topic), so `FileWritePost` wouldn't make sense. Just when the current buffer is saved, run the commands.

Answer (score 2):

`BufWritePost` is the event you typically want. It needs to be a `Post` event because you want to source the contents of the file *after* they've been saved.

It's conceivable you might also want to cover `FileWritePost`, in case you want to also source a `*.vim` file when you write it through an operation taking a range, such as `:'<,'>w newfile.vim` with a Visual selection, to create a new Vimscript file with only parts of the current buffer, perhaps you're splitting a function into its own script file...

Also note you should use `<afile>` for the path of the file that matched the autocmd. It's not necessarily `%`, especially in the `FileWritePost` case.

You might also want to cover the vimrc file through the same rule. You need to list its possible paths explicitly, since they don't really match `*.vim`.

```
augroup vimscript_source
  au!
  au BufWritePost,FileWritePost *.vim,~/.vimrc,~/.vim/vimrc source <afile>
augroup END
```